# Porqué no funciona correctamente couchdb y fauxton en windows 10

Tags: json, couchdb

Situación actual:

Luego de instalar couchdb en Windows 10 usando el instalador apache-couchdb-2.3.1.msi y configurar su funcionamiento como un nodo simple con los datos:

- User: Admin (Es solo para pruebas)
- Password: Pass (Demasiado inseguro? es solo para pruebas!)
- Puerto: 5984
- Ip: 127.0.0.1

Se verifico la instalación: http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#/verifyinstall

Al crear una base de datos "prueba" esta se crea correctamente y al crear un nuevo documento este se crea correctamente.

Problema:

Al agregar información al documento creado y presionar el botón "Save Changes" no pasa nada no se guardan los cambios.

Documento sin modificar:

```
{
  "_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2",
  "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"
}
```

Documento modificado (Los cambios no se guardan)

```
{
  "_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2",
  "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"
  "data": "Hello World"
}
```

El botón solo funciona cuando el documento no ha sufrido cambios o cuando elimino los datos agregados "data" también he probado agregar la coma "," al final de cada linea

```
{
  "_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2",
  "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d",
  "data": "Hello World",
}
```

Igual sin ningún resultado, he probado usando Firefox y Chrome, he probado deshabilitar los plugins y addons en esos navegadores

Comment: CouchDb o Couchbase? No son mismo

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto: el problema era la sintaxis JSON :)

Faltaba una coma antes del último par clave-valor:

```
{
  "_id": "e940717f486026242e9b5d9cd80023d2",
  "_rev": "1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d"
  "data": "Hello World"
}
```